# Google Colab: FileNotFoundError: Cannot find file

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

On Colab, I cannot download a file generated by the python script.

The issue is simple and easy to reproduce.

1.

Example colab url: https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/nst_blogpost/4_Neural_Style_Transfer_with_Eager_Execution.ipynb

2.

change the code as the instruction on the colab notebook.

```
#from google.colab import files
#files.download('wave_turtle.png')
```

to

```
from google.colab import files
files.download('wave_turtle.png')
```

3. 

Run the all cells with F9

4.

you must get the error as below. And so, I cannot save the file generated.

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-b9f28ce5d1dd> in <module>()
      1 from google.colab import files
----> 2 files.download('wave_turtle.png')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/files.py in download(filename)
    141       raise OSError(msg)
    142     else:
--> 143       raise FileNotFoundError(msg)  # pylint: disable=undefined-variable
    144 
    145   comm_manager = _IPython.get_ipython().kernel.comm_manager

FileNotFoundError: Cannot find file: wave_turtle.png
```

Is this colab's problem? or problem on my side? Thanks.